# Changing getElementById to getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am sure is a common problem in JS, i have created resizing function using JS, initially this function was only going to be used on one item of my site, however now i have chosen to use it on multiple items.  My JS function currently uses `document.getElementById(id);` however i want to change this so it looks out for the class name `.resize`. How can this be done?
 Below is a snippet of my JS

```
function ebi(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    if(ebi('resize')
        .complete==true){
        iscale(ebi(''));
    } 
    ebi('resize')
    .onload=function(){iscale(this);
    }

    function iscale(o){
        //alert(o.width);
    var sar=o.width/o.height;
    var tar=1,tiw,tih,xoff,yoff;
    if(o.width<=425&&o.height<=467){
        tiw=o.width;
        tih=o.height;
    }else if(tar>sar){
        tiw=425*sar;
        tih=467;
    }
    else{
        tiw=425;
        tih=467/sar;
    }
    xoff=(680-tiw)>>1;
    yoff=(209-tih)>>1;
    //alert(xoff);
    o.width=tiw;o.height=tih;
    o.style.top=yoff+"px";
    o.style.left=xoff+"px";
    }
function $(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
```

html

```
 <section id="homeSlide" class="shadow">
    <img id="resize"class='opaque' src="http://www.colette.fr/media/push/pony_01239.jpg" />
    <img id="resize" src="http://www.colette.fr/media/push/EGIFT_01234.jpg" />
    <img id="resize" src="http://www.colette.fr/media/push/swa_mmm_001255.jpg" />
</section>
```

At the moment the resize function only works for the first image, however the other images do not resize. Before anyone attacks me about web standards the `id`'s in the img tags were just to test the function.

Comment: have you tried document.getElementsByClassName?? change all your img id to class and try

Comment: @Gowsikan yup tried that however i get an error, i thought is was as simple as that myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the point is `id` should be unique and to do what you want why don't you use `jQuery`. using jQuery you can easily do what you want, using this

```
jQuery("#homeSlide>img")
```

and you can also add this:

```
jQuery("#homeSlide>img").each(function(imgNode){
    resize(imgNode);
});
```

but if you want to do it without `jQuery`, as far as some functions like `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` are not cross browser, you'd better try this:

```
var homeSlide = document.getElementById('homeSlide');
var myImgNodes = [];
for(var i=0;i<homeSlide.childNodes.length;i++){
    var childNode = homeSlide.childNodes[i];
    if(childNode.nodeType==1 && childNode.tagName.toLowerCase()=="img"){
        myImgNodes.push(childNode);
    }
}
```

afterwards `myImgNodes` would be exactly what you want.

I just changed your fiddle example and tried not to change your functionality, you can check this out, it perfectly works. [This is your updated jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QFK6Y/1/)

Comment: hence me saying in my question "Before anyone attacks me about web standards the id's in the img tags were just to test the function."

Comment: I didn't mean to attack you, as I had gone through this very arduous task, I just wanted to save you a bit of time, anyway sorry about that. have a great time.

Comment: I just add a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QFK6Y/1/) to my answer and removed those bad lines.

Answer (score 1):

id have to be unique, that's why this didn't works.

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName()` (as you thought) : simply add `class="resize"` (instead of `id="resize"`) and use that kind of loop:

```
function callResize()
{ 
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("resize");
  for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
  {
    var element = elements[i];
    // do things with element
    iscale(element);
  }
}
document.getElementById('homeSlide').onload = function(){callResize();}
```

Comment: Slight confused here, i have my JS as the following which is giving me an error message...http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/QFK6Y/

Comment: you don't need to declare the function $(id) neither ebi. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Hey man, i'm struggle to get this to work, would you be able to upload it onto jsfiddle

Comment: On the link you gave there is `getElemntsByClassName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. + in jsfiddle, you have to put separately html, js and css : html is empty, and there is <script> tags in the js part (which gives probably errors). Try and test your code with a javascript console opened (firebug for example)

Answer (score 0):

First, an ID has to be unique in your HTML document. But in your example code you assign the ID "resize" three times. Just replace the ID from all three elements and add `class="resize"`.

Second, I suggest to use the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method to iterate over the returned collection instead of a loop.

Example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("resize")

jQuery.each(elements, function(element) {
  iscale(element)
})
```